# Postgres INSERT INTO with SELECT ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql

When inserting into Postgres via a `select` statement, are the rows guaranteed to be inserted in the same order that the select statement returns them?

That is, given a table `bar` (where `id` is `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, and `name` is `TEXT`):

```
id | name
---+-----
 0 | A
 1 | B
 2 | C
```

And another table, `foo` (empty and with the same schema), if I `INSERT INTO foo (name) SELECT name FROM bar ORDER BY id DESC` will `foo` be guaranteed to have:

```
id | name
---+-----
 0 | C
 1 | B
 2 | A
```

This seems to be the case, but I'd like to confirm that it isn't an implementation detail that may not hold with larger selects.

I read through section 13.8 in the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) and general rule #3 claims that "The query expression is effectively evaluated before inserting any rows into B.", but it doesn't explicitly say anything about ordering. Is the standard purposefully vague (perhaps to allow parallel insertions?) and ordering is an implementation detail?

Comment: This [DBA Stack Exchange article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95822/does-postgres-preserve-insertion-order-of-records) seems to say no.  You should not rely on any internal order to your tables.

Comment: Any RDBMS is ultimately an **unordered set** of data - you **only ever** get ordering on a `SELECT` if you explicitly specify an `ORDER BY`

Comment: @marc_s And there is an ORDER BY here, it’s just a question will INSERT process the results in that order or not

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: whether or not the insert is processed in this particular order is **irrelevant**, since the data is inserted into an **unordered set** - it doesn't matter in what order it is inserted - there **IS NO** system-inherent ordering. If you want to get it out in any ordered fashion, you **MUST** use an explicit `ORDER BY` on your `SELECT` query

Comment: @marc_s It’s very much not irrelevant. There’s a sequence used to create an ID. It very much is a question of insert order and side effects. Not what the results are when queried back. Same would be with triggers, will they be run in the order the SELECT query returns rows or not.

Comment: This is an interesting question. While MySQL states in their docs that `ORDER BY` does matter, and for SQL Server there are Microsoft people confirming this, too, I could find nothing for PostgreSQL (or Oracle for that matter) on the Internet. I think that this should clearly stated in the documentation. For PostgreSQL there is a link down in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html leading you to a form where you should be able to ask them to include an explanation on `ORDER BY` in `INSERT SELECT`in their docs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for the reply. Fortunately, I'm not interested in the internal order (that is, the `ctid` order isn't important to me). I'm trying to understand the semantics of `insert`. That is, will inserting the results of a select be the same as looping over the select and performing an explicit insert per each row.

Comment: @Steve That doesn't really matter, because as Laurenz' answer below discusses, there is no internal order per se.  So, the order in which records in an insert get inserted does not really matter.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, thanks for chiming in. @marc_s, similarly thanks for the reply but Sami is correct here. This is a question of semantics around `insert`. I agree that the set, by default, isn't ordered, but this set *is* ordered by definition of having a serial primary key (will modify question to clarify). The set has at least one defined ordering, the order of item insertion (again, by definition of `SERIAL`). The question is: Does `insert` have well-defined semantics here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I believe Laurenz overlooked that we do use an `ORDER BY` clause to impose order. We don't rely on internal order. Similarly, we impose order on the target table via a `SERIAL` primary key. We explicitly impose ordering on both sets. The ambiguity here is what are `insert`'s semantics around inserting rows from one ordered set into another ordered set, where the target set's order is defined as 'insertion order'.

Sorry if this is poorly worded or ambiguously phrased. Trying to be precise.

Comment: @Steve I see what you mean.  The article I quoted initially seems to say that order is preserved if you're using a `VALUES` clause.  Not sure about `ORDER BY` though.  I understand that you want the IDs to be assigned in a certain order.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks. Yea, I saw that `VALUES` have order preserved. I'm wondering if that applies to `SELECT` clauses as well. I appreciate the replies while clarifying!

Comment: The insert is **not** guaranteed to "mimic" the order of the select. For example the "insert order" might be different into a newly created table compared to one that contained rows that were removed using `delete`  and yet another "order" for a table that contained rows that were removed using `truncate` and yet another "order" if only half of the rows had been deleted. For a `SELECT` statement the **only** (really: the _only_) way to get a **guaranteed** order is to use an `order by`. There is no alternative to that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That could be answer to a highly upvoted question :-)

Comment: @Steve . . . This is an interesting question.  I know that SQL Server guarantees the order of an `identity` column based on the `order by` in an insert subquery.  I am guessing that Postgres does so as well . . . but before believing anyone who says "it works", I would want to see how it works on a parallel implementation using a parallel insert mechanism.

Answer (score 12):

I asked over on the Postgres mailing-list and they were helpful in clarifying. It turns out that this is a database specific answer, so if you're reading this and using a different database the answer may not be the same.

Postgres, explicitly as of 9.6, will logically insert in the order of the returned result set.

The behavior is explicitly codified in this commit: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/9118d03a8cca3d97327c56bf89a72e328e454e63

From the commit description:

> For example, in   SELECT x, nextval('seq') FROM tab ORDER BY x LIMIT
> 10; it's probably desirable that the nextval() values are ordered the
> same as x, and that nextval() is not run more than 10 times.
>
> In the past, Postgres was inconsistent in this area: you would get the
> desirable behavior if the ordering were performed via an indexscan,
> but not if it had to be done by an explicit sort step.

To quote the mailing list response from Tom Lane at https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/29386.1528813619%40sss.pgh.pa.us :

> What is actually going to happen, given say

> ```
> create table targ (d text, id serial);
> insert into targ select x from src order by y;
> ```

> is that you're going to get a parse tree equivalent to

> ```
>  select x, nextval('targ_id_seq')
>  from (select x from src order by y) ss;
> ```

> and then it's a question of whether the planner is capable of reordering the steps into something you don't want.  I think that the presence of the explicit "ORDER BY" in the sub-select will prevent flattening of the sub-select, which is enough to make it safe.  However, if  for some reason
> you did not say "ORDER BY" but nonetheless expected the serial values to get assigned in the same order that the underlying query would produce rows natively, you might get burnt.
> As of 9.6, there are more guarantees in this area than there used to be (cf commit 9118d03a8), but I don't think it matters as long as you write an ORDER BY.

tl;dr; The insertion ordering is an implementation detail, but purposefully coded in Postgres 9.6 and above to match one's intuition. Prior to 9.6, there were no guarantees.

Comment: any chance you could point to that mailing list and the discussion?  the linked commit you show has nothing to do with INSERT

Comment: found it https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADBwkHv1nUx5bqxqRLp26k8iUWSnY3uW-1_0EMYxKns0t2JnUA%40mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 5):

The rows in the new table will be inserted in the order specified by the `ORDER BY` clause, so the `id` generated from the sequence will reflect this order.

To verify that, look at the execution plan, where you should be able to see a `Sort` node before the `Insert`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but note in my sample query there *is* an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: The last paragraph answers your question. The rest is supposed to address your concerns about the SQL standard.

Comment: I found the last paragraph a little ambiguous. Will the items be inserted in the order that they are returned from the `select` query? And why would this change for a non-empty table?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think the OP just wants to know if `ORDER BY` is used with a select, would the auto increment IDs themselves correspond to the insertion order which the corresponding select would generate?

Comment: I have modified the answer, now it should be what you need.