# insert into a table that have triggers with select

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

i have make this trigger to keep the ordering ( so the first number should be 1 and the next should be 2 ... for table haltenummer )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_volgorde_haltenummer()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM trip_station_planning r WHERE
    r.tripcode=NEW.tripcode
        AND
        r.haltenummer >= NEW.haltenummer ) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'JE HEBT EEN ONGELIDE HALTENUMMER TOEGEVOEGD';
    END IF;
    
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM trip_station_planning r WHERE
    r.tripcode=NEW.tripcode and 
         
        r.haltenummer + 1 = NEW.haltenummer  ) and NEW.haltenummer != 1 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'JE HEBT EEN ONGELIDE HALTENUMMER TOEGEVOEGD!!';
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.check_volgorde_haltenummer()
    OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER check_volgorde_haltenummer_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.trip_station_planning
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.check_volgorde_haltenummer();
```

and when I try to insert data from another table using select distinct
`insert into trip_station_planning (tripcode , haltenummer , date  )select tripcode , haltenummer , date from  my_table order by tripcode , haltenummer` I get fout `JE HEBT EEN ONGELIDE HALTENUMMER TOEGEVOEGD!!`, so is there another way to do it without triggers ? or maybe there is something wrong with my trigger   `NOT EXISTS` , by the way the data in the other table is right , so the problem is the trigger .

Comment: (a) Can you explain how you can "insert data from another table using select" ? (b) Can you show the trigger definition : `CREATE TRIGGER ...`

Comment: @Edouard
 i have data in another table , and i want to full my new table with part of it ,  i edited the post , i guess that the probleem with if  NOT EXISTS , beco the table is empty ,

Comment: It sounds like you get the result in conformance with your `check_volgorde_haltenummer` function definition : when you insert a new row in table `trip_station_planning` you raise exceptions if conditions are met in this function, and then you stop the insert process because the trigger is `BEFORE INSERT`. What else would you like to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @Edouard  i would like to achieve if  NOT new haltenummer = any haltenummer  + 1
then there is somthing wrong , with other words , order  trigger

Comment: Does the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809120/postgres-insert-into-with-select-ordering) answer your question ?